# do not want string as type when using foreach in scala spark streaming?

Tags: scala, utf-8, deserialization, spark-streaming, avro

code snippet :

```
val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, group, topicMap)
val write2hdfs = lines.filter(x => x._1 == "lineitem").map(_._2)
write2hdfs.foreachRDD(rdd => {

rdd.foreach(avroRecord => {
println(avroRecord)
//val rawByte = avroRecord.getBytes("UTF-8")
```

Issue faced>

avroRecord holds avro encoded messages received from kafka stream.
By default avroRecord is a string when the above code is being used.
And string has UTF-16 encoding as default in scala.

Due this deserialization is not correct and facing issues.
Messages were encoded into avro with utf-8 when sent to kafka stream.

I would need avroRecord to be pure bytes **instead** of getting as string and then converting to bytes(internally string would do utf-16 encoding).

or a way to get avroRecord itself in utf-8. Stuck here deadblock.

Need a way forward for this problem statement.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

Code snippet changed >

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(5))
//val ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(5))
val topicMap = topics.split(",").map((_, numThreads.toInt)).toMap
val kafkaParams = Map[String, String]("zookeeper.connect" -> 
zkQuorum,"group.id" -> group,"zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms" -> "10000")                    

//val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, group, topicMap)
val lines = 
KafkaUtils.createStream[String,Message,StringDecoder,DefaultDecoder]
(ssc,kafkaParams,topics,StorageLevel.NONE)
```

imports done :

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.toPairDStreamFunctions
import org.apache.avro
import org.apache.avro.Schema
import org.apache.avro.generic.{GenericDatumReader, GenericRecord, 
GenericDatumWriter, GenericData}
import org.apache.avro.io.{DecoderFactory, DatumReader, DatumWriter, 
BinaryDecoder}
import org.apache.avro.file.{DataFileReader, DataFileWriter}
import java.io.{File, IOException}
//import java.io.*
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import _root_.kafka.serializer.{StringDecoder, DefaultDecoder}
import _root_.kafka.message.Message
import scala.reflect._
```

Compilation error :

Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/spark_scala/spark_stream_project/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[error] /home/spark_scala/spark_stream_project/src/main/scala/sparkStreaming.scala:34: overloaded method value createStream with alternatives:
[error]   (jssc: org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext,keyTypeClass: Class[String],valueTypeClass: Class[kafka.message.Message],keyDecoderClass: Class[kafka.serializer.StringDecoder],valueDecoderClass: Class[kafka.serializer.DefaultDecoder],kafkaParams: java.util.Map[String,String],topics: java.util.Map[String,Integer],storageLevel: org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel)org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairReceiverInputDStream[String,kafka.message.Message] 
[error]   (ssc: org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext,kafkaParams: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String],topics: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int],storageLevel: org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel)(implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[String], implicit evidence$2: scala.reflect.ClassTag[kafka.message.Message], implicit evidence$3: scala.reflect.ClassTag[kafka.serializer.StringDecoder], implicit evidence$4: scala.reflect.ClassTag[kafka.serializer.DefaultDecoder])org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ReceiverInputDStream[(String, kafka.message.Message)]
[error]  cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext, scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String], String, org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel)
[error]                 val lines = KafkaUtils.createStreamString,Message,StringDecoder,DefaultDecoder
[error]                                                    ^

### [error] one error found

What is wrong here.
Also, i dont see the correct constructor as suggested being defined in the kafkaUtils API doc.
API Doc ref am referring :
    https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/java/index.html?
    org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka/KafkaUtils.html

looking forward for support.

Thanks.

**UPDATE 2:**

Tried with corrections suggested!

code snippet>

```
val lines = 
KafkaUtils.createStream[String,Message,StringDecoder,DefaultDecoder]
(ssc,kafkaParams,topicMap,StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2)
val write2hdfs = lines.filter(x => x._1 == "lineitem").map(_._2)
```

Facing runtime exception>

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to kafka.message.Message

On line :
KafkaUtils.createStream[String,Message,StringDecoder,DefaultDecoder]
(ssc,kafkaParams,topicMap,StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2)
val write2hdfs = lines.filter(x => x._1 == "lineitem").map(_._2)
```

ideally filter this Dstream(String,Message) should also work right ?
Do i need to extract the payload from Message before subjecting to map ?

need inputs please.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
import kafka.serializer.{StringDecoder, DefaultDecoder}
import kafka.message.Message

val kafkaParams = Map[String, String](
    "zookeeper.connect" -> zkQuorum, "group.id" -> group,
    "zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms" -> "10000")
val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream[String, Message, StringDecoder, DefaultDecoder](
      ssc, kafkaParams, topics, storageLevel)
```

This should get you a `DStream[(String, kafka.message.Message)]`, and you should be able to retrieve the raw bytes and convert to Avro from there.

Comment: Thanks a lot joe for the inputs.  i will update the original post with the results.

Comment: Have updated the original post with the latest code change results as suggested. kindly help to understand what's wrong in the implementation.

Comment: Looks like you need to pass `topicMap`, not `topics` to createStream. Also, the documentation you have linked is old. Here's what I was looking at: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils

Comment: Thanks Joe, it was my mistake. overseen the topics variable.Updated with latest result. still there is a classcastexception. have updated the original post again. Need ur valuable insights.

Comment: Joe, thanks for the support. Just did a small tweaking and changed Message to Array[Byte] which solved my problem. It would be good if you can give insights on converting kafka.message.Message as well to Byte Array or how to use it if required.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
val lines = 
KafkaUtils.createStream[String,Array[Byte],StringDecoder,DefaultDecoder]
(ssc,kafkaParams,topicMap,StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2)
```

My requirement was to get the Byte Array, so changed to Array[Byte] instead of kafka.message.Message